# ¿Cómo llamar a código C++ desde Python?

Tags: python

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:
Necesito limitar la precisión de los resultados que tengo en una simulación de python usando Q-numbers. Una de las ideas que tengo en mente es hacer una clase en c++ que, con ayuda de máscaras tales como << ó | , dichos números queden en forma Q.

Existe alguna librería en python que trabaje directamente con los bits como en C++, o como se podría hacer para que la propia clase en C++, sea llamada desde python y usada a lo largo de la simulación?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola A.Her, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow. Tu segunda pregunta es un poco amplia: si estás pensando en importar un módulo en C++ concreto es mejor que hagas una pregunta separada.

Comment: Para la primera pregunta, le puedes echar un ojo al módulo `decimal` de la biblioteca estándar: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html. Para la segunda pregunta, como comenta @astrojuanlu, es una pregunta muy amplia.

Comment: La cuestión seria que quiero limitar los números decimales mediante bits a una precisión determinada, por ejemplo Q15,2. y creo que eso la libreía decimal no lo hace de esta manera trabaja mas bien con decimales, ¿no, @kikocorreoso @astrojuanlu? Por otro lado, lo de la segunda cuestión va encaminada porque como c dispone de mascaras tales como << ó | (or) seria mas sencillo hacerlo en ese lenguaje y después importar ese modulo a mi main en python, pero soy bastante novata en   estos temas, y la verdad ando un poco perdida. ¡Muchas gracias por ayudarme!

Comment: @A-her, también en python tienes `<<` y `|` para operaciones en binario. No he encontrado librería en python para manejar [*Q-numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28number_format%29), pero no debería ser complicado programarse una clase para estas operaciones.

Comment: @A-her quizá si editas la pregunta y pones algo más descriptivo, código de ejemplo sobre lo que quieres hacer,..., encontremos mejores respuestas.

Comment: Tal y como ha quedado la respuesta de @kikocorreoso (yo tampoco he encontrado bibliotecas para Q-numbers en Python) sugiero cambiar la pregunta a **¿Cómo llamar a código C++ desde Python?** para que quede más claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para la primera pregunta no he encontrado respuesta y tampoco entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer ni lo he hecho nunca. Para la segunda pregunta se podría crear algo con CFFI o con Cython.

## Un ejemplo con Cython

(antes de nada instala Cython si no lo tienes instalado usando `pip install cython` (o `conda install cython` si usas conda))

- Primero, vamos a crear la parte de C++ usando una función simple que sume dos enteros:

El fichero *milibreria.hpp* contendrá:

```
long suma_enteros(long n, long m);
```

El fichero *milibreria.cpp* contendrá:

```
long suma_enteros(long n, long m){
    return n + m;
}
```

- Segundo, vamos a crear la parte Cython:

Necesitamos definir un fichero *milibreria.pxd* que nos ayudará a 'encontrar' lo que hemos definido en c++ (más info sobre [los ficheros pxd aquí](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html)):

```
cdef extern from "milibreria.hpp":
    long suma_enteros(long n, long m)
```

Ahora necesitamos hacer que la parte c++ sea accesible desde Python, para ello creamos el fichero *pylibfromcpp.pyx*, que es una especie de código Python un poco 'cythonizado':

```
cimport milibreria

def suma_enteros(n, m):
    return milibreria.suma_enteros(n, m)
```

- Tercero, creamos el *setup.py*

Para poder acceder a la librería c++ hemos de crear un fichero *setup.py* que nos permitirá crear la extensión a la que accederemos desde Python. El fichero *setup.py* contendrá:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext = Extension("pylibfromcpp",
              sources=["pylibfromcpp.pyx", "milibreria.cpp"],
              language="c++",)

setup(name = "cython_pylibfromcpp",
      ext_modules = cythonize(ext))
```

Para crear la extensión en sí, en la misma carpeta donde hemos dejado todos los ficheros anteriores y desde la línea de comandos hacemos **(recomiendo hacer esto desde un entorno virtual)**:

```
python setup.py build_ext -i
```

Ahora, si todo ha salido bien, dentro de un intérprete de python podemos hacer:

```
import pylibfromcpp
print(pylibfromcpp.suma_enteros(2, 3))
```

Y el resultado debería ser `5`.

[Documentación de Cython](http://docs.cython.org/index.html) para ampliar esta mini explicación.

## Un ejemplo con CFFI

(deberás instalar antes `cffi` mediante `pip install cffi` o `conda install cffi`)

- Primero, creamos un fichero que se llamará *milibreria_cffi.cpp*

El fichero tendrá el siguiente contenido:

```
long suma_enteros(long n, long m){
    return n + m;
}

extern "C"
{
    extern long cffi_suma_enteros(long n, long m)
    {
        return suma_enteros(n, m);
    }
}
```

La misma función `suma_enteros` de antes más una parte para poder hacerlo accesible desde Python.

- Segundo, creamos un fichero Python.

Este ficheto se llamará *pylibfromCFFI.py*

```
import cffi


ffi = cffi.FFI()
ffi.cdef("long cffi_suma_enteros(long n, long m);")
C = ffi.dlopen("./milibreria.so")


def suma_enteros(n, m):
    return C.cffi_suma_enteros(n, m)
```

que nos permitirá llamar a la función definida en c++.

Ahora compilamos el fichero c++:

```
g++ -o ./milibreria.so ./milibreria_cffi.cpp -fPIC -shared
```

Y desde la misma carpeta podemos abrir un intéprete de Python y escribir:

```
import pylibfromCFFI
print(pylibfromCFFI.suma_enteros(2, 3))
```

Y el resultado, sorprendentemente, debería volver a ser `5`.

[Documentación de cffi](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

[Aquí tienes un ejemplo más completo](http://pybonacci.org/2016/02/07/como-crear-extensiones-en-c-para-python-usando-cffi-y-numba/) del uso de CFFI con C escrito por @astrojuanlu en su maravilloso blog!!!

## Otras formas

No las recomiendo!!!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @kikocorreoso. ¡Me es de gran ayuda!

Comment: En _nuestro_ maravilloso blog :P

Comment: No se le puede hacer publicidad al blog? que no veo el nombre xD

Comment: En la respuesta tienes un enlace a un post que comento y el enlace al blog en general es este: [pybonacci](http://pybonacci.org)